# How can I change the tolerance ratio in HPA k8s, without actually changing it?

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

I have a k8s cluster that contains multiple services - each of them should have a different HPA autoscaler, thus, the tolerance (0.1 by default) is different. In addition, every autoscaler uses custom metric.

Is there a way to change it for a specific amount of pods? I guess it's not possible. So I'm trying to think about a mathematical way to do that - to create a custom metric (from my current metric).
Is someone familiar with this issue? (different usage of tolerance value on the same cluster)

I tried to use the tolerance default value, and play with the stabilization window, with the period, but nothing works well.